# Mixed content warning on doctype in admin

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, https

I'm getting a strange error on my live WordPress website. On the admin homepage, I'm getting a mixed content warning that points to the doctype. If I copy this entire website and database to my local machine, I'm unable to produce the error. It only occurs on the home page of wp-admin, and prevents other things from working - for example, when hovering over Posts or other links on the left-nav, I don't get the sub-navigation on hover - but if I right click, they appear.

The warning seems to point to itself:

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://domain.co.uk/wp-admin/index.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://domain.co.uk/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS`.

This error started to appear after upgrading to WordPress 4.9.

[image: WordPress Mixed Content Error]

Comment: Can you see any scripts in the source code that are loading with the insecure protocol http:// ?

Comment: There aren't any http requests in the source code of wp-admin. The error seems to say that the script it's trying to load is `http://www.domain.co.uk`, without the https - which is really odd. It doesn't actually show that it's trying to load a file, just the domain itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be [Wordfence causing the issue](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/dashboard-mixed-content-error/).